# MongoDB - $gruop, secondary $group, $sum fields using multiple lookups

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to use a mongo aggregation query to look at a bunch of data, and retrieve it in a way that is useful to me. mainly because I want all the sorting logic to happen on the DB, and not do it manually in the server.

so I have ***projects, users, timers***

**projects** collection:

```
{id: 1, name: "project A"}
{id: 2, name: "project X"}
{id: 3, name: "project C"}
```

**users** collection:

```
{id: 1, name: "John"}
{id: 2, name: "Jane"}
{id: 3, name: "James"}
```

**timers** collection:

```
{id: 1, projectId: 3, userId: 2, startTime: (date ISO), endTime: (date ISO)}
{id: 2, projectId: 1, userId: 3, startTime: (date ISO), endTime: (date ISO)}
{id: 3, projectId: 1, userId: 1, startTime: (date ISO), endTime: (date ISO)}
{id: 4, projectId: 1, userId: 1, startTime: (date ISO), endTime: (date ISO)}
{id: 5, projectId: 2, userId: 1, startTime: (date ISO), endTime: (date ISO)}
```

what I'm looking to achieve from mongo using aggregation, is a response object that will reflect grouping by a "main" category, inside it will be grouped by "secondary" category- and each entry will hold the sum of durations (endTime minus startTime, of each timer)

so lets say my main group is project, and secondary is user, I also want to see names sorted alphabetically, and not id's. so the expected result should be:

```
[
    { project A: [
        { James: (*the sum of durations for all Jamses' timers on project 1*) },
        { John: (*the sum of durations for all John's timers on project 1*) },
                 ]
     },
    { project B: [
        { John: (*the sum of durations for all Jane's timers on project 3*) },
                 ]
     },
    { project X: [
        { Jane: (*the sum of durations for all John's timers on project 2*) },
                 ]
     },
]
```

I would love if someone can try and figure that out, on how to achieve this behavior with a single aggregation call. I've tried many combinations of pipeline operators, but cannot seem to get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

```
db.timers.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "users",
                let: {"uId": "$userId" },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$uId"] }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                as: "userInfo"
            }  
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "project",
                let: {"pId": "$projectId" },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$pId"] }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                as: "projectInfo"
            }  
        },
        { $unwind: "$userInfo" },
        { $unwind: "$projectInfo" },
        {
            $group: {
                _id:  { "pname":"$projectInfo.name", "uname": "$userInfo.name" } ,
                sumOfDurationInMinutes: { $sum: { $divide:[ { $subtract: ["$endTime", "$startTime"] }, 60000 ]} } 
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$_id.pname",
                data: { $push: "$$ROOT"}
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Response Result :

```
{
    "_id" : "project C",
    "data" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "pname" : "project C",
                "uname" : "Jane"
            },
            "sumOfDurationInMinutes" : 60
        }
    ]
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "project A",
    "data" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "pname" : "project A",
                "uname" : "John"
            },
            "sumOfDurationInMinutes" : 120
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "pname" : "project A",
                "uname" : "James"
            },
            "sumOfDurationInMinutes" : 60
        }
    ]
},

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "project X",
    "data" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "pname" : "project X",
                "uname" : "John"
            },
            "sumOfDurationInMinutes" : 60
        }
    ]
}
```